# Script to download images in Array PHP

Tags: php

I have a script which downloads images from their URL in array and copies the images to a folder on server.
The /folder/ has writing rights (CHMOD 777).
I get an error (dowwload failed for...), what is wrong in this script?

```
<?php
$IMAGES = 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/groove-marketing-assets/games-prod/1X2%20Gaming/10s%20Or%20Better.png,https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/groove-marketing-assets/games-prod/1X2%20Gaming/Alice%20and%20the%20Red%20Queen.png,https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/groove-marketing-assets/games-prod/1X2%20Gaming/All%20American.png,https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/groove-marketing-assets/games-prod/1X2%20Gaming/Astro%20Roulette.png';

    $images = explode(', ',$IMAGES); 

    foreach($images as $image) {

       $name = basename($image);
       $newfile = 'https://myserver.com/folder/'.$name;

       if(copy($image, $newfile)){
          echo 'Successfully downloaded '. $image;
       }else{
          echo 'Download failed for '. $image;
       }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: `$newfile = 'https://myserver.com/folder/'.$name;` you should use file system pathes and not the url for the new files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things are a bit out of place here:

1. Your string of URLs is separated by a single comma (`,`).

   ```
   $IMAGES = 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/groove-marketing-assets/games-prod/1X2%20Gaming/10s%20Or%20Better.png,https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/groove-marketing-assets/games-prod/1X2%20Gaming/Alice%20and%20the%20Red%20Queen.png,https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/groove-marketing-assets/games-prod/1X2%20Gaming/All%20American.png,https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/groove-marketing-assets/games-prod/1X2%20Gaming/Astro%20Roulette.png';
   ```

   However, you're `explode()`-ing by a single comma **followed by a space** (`,`).

   ```
   $images = explode(', ',$IMAGES);
   ```

   Your array won't be generated correctly:

   ```
   var_dump($images);
   /* Output:
   array(1) {
     [0]=>
     string(429) "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/groove-marketing-assets/games-prod/1X2%20Gaming/10s%20Or%20Better.png,https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/groove-marketing-assets/games-prod/1X2%20Gaming/Alice%20and%20the%20Red%20Queen.png,https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/groove-marketing-assets/games-prod/1X2%20Gaming/All%20American.png,https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/groove-marketing-assets/games-prod/1X2%20Gaming/Astro%20Roulette.png"
   }
   */
   ```

   Change your `explode()` call to break up the items by the correct delimiter (a single comma):

   ```
   $images = explode(',',$IMAGES);
   ```
2. You're attempting to copy to an HTTP path:

   ```
   $newfile = 'https://myserver.com/folder/'.$name;
   ```

   [From the PHP docts on `copy()`](https://www.php.net/copy):

   > If **dest** is a URL, the copy operation may fail if the wrapper does not support overwriting of existing files.

   Instead, refer to a local system file path. (The correct path string will depend on your server's OS.)